# Reloading last active tab after page refresh (Bootstrap)

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I'm building an MVC application and in my view i use bootstrap tabs. Now, what i want to to is to reload last active tab after refreshing the page or redirecting to it from the controller. Any help on how can i do this in the simplest way?
This is my code:

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active">
            <a href="#Stages" data-toggle="tab">Stages</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#Activities" data-toggle="tab">Activities</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#History" data-toggle="tab">History</a>
        </li>       
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="Stages">                
            @Html.Partial("_Stages", Model.stages)
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="Activities">
            @Html.Partial("_Activities", Model.activities)
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="History">
            @Html.Partial("_History", Model.history)
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: One way would be to keep track of the active tab, and have your controller update the model with that information for the view to use. Add your controller code here and maybe it can be modified appropriately.

Comment: i tried like this in the controller 
</br>return new RedirectResult(Url.Action("Action", "Controller", new { ID = id }) + "#Stages");<br/>
but it doesn't change class of the Stages tab to active, I don't know how to achieve that

Comment: You need to either add the 'active' class based on data binding or set it using jQuery after/when rendering the view.

Answer (score 1):

1. Try checking `location.href.hash` on client side and manipulate tab selection accordingly.
2. Or else you will have to use some navigation/history client libraries like `nav.js` or `sammy.js`. This can register tab clicks in browser history stack with hash path. And with URL hash you can manipulate the tab selection
3. You can refer to [Sammy Implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16192788/how-to-retain-an-injected-partial-view-after-page-refresh-in-asp-net-mvc/16193175#16193175)

Answer (score 0):

**[TwitterBootstrapMVC](https://www.twitterbootstrapmvc.com/)** allows passing active tab number through an extension method:

```
using (var tabs = Html.Bootstrap().Begin(new Tabs("TabsId").ActiveTab(2)))
{
    @tabs.Tab("Tab 1")
    @tabs.Tab("Tab 2")
    @tabs.Tab("Tab 3")

    using (tabs.BeginPanel())
    {
        <p>Contents of tab 1</p>
    }
    using (tabs.BeginPanel())
    {
        <p>Contents of tab 2</p>
    }
    using (tabs.BeginPanel())
    {
        <p>Contents of tab 3</p>
    }
}
```

So if you have information in your model about the tab you want to be on, you could use that.